# Добрый день можете подсказать ка окно Tkiner в питон открыть позади ярлыков и панели задач в виндовс 10 и запретить его двигать?

Tags: python-3.x

Добрый день можете подсказать ка окно Tkiner в питон открыть позади ярлыков и панели задач в виндовс 10 и запретить его двигать

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)